# Question regarding motivation of spectral theorem for unitary operators

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, representation-theory, ergodic-theory

$\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}$
$\newcommand{\ab}[1]{\langle #1\rangle}$

Theorem B.4 in Einsiedler and Ward's [EW] *Ergodic Theory with a view towards Number Theory* states the following:

> **Theorem 1.**
>   ***Spectral Theorem.***
>   Let $U $be a unitary operator on a complex Hilbert space $H$.
>   $(1)$ For each element $f\in H$, there is a unique Borel measure $\mu_f$ on $S^1$ with the property that
>   $$
> \ab{U^nf, f} = \int_{S^1} z^n\ d\mu_f(z)
> $$
>   (2) The map
>   $$
> \sum_{n=-N}^N c_nz^n \mapsto \sum_{n=-N}^N c_n U^n f
> $$
>   extends by continuity to a unitary isomorphism between $L^2(S^1, \mu_f)$ and the smallest $U$-invariant subspace in $H$ containing $f$.

(There was some text here. Thanks to @DisintegrationByParts for pointing our an error. I have thus removed the text.)

> **Question 1.**
>   I do not see any motivation for the theorem.
>   The statement seems out of the blue. Can somebody provide some perspective here?

Lastly, let $(X, \mc F, \mu, T)$ be a measure-preserving system.
Thus $U_T:L^2(X, \mu)\to L^2(X, \mu)$ defined as $f\mapsto f\circ T$ is a unitary operator.

> **Question 2.**
>   If $g\in L^2(X, \mu)$, what is the meaning of the phrase ``By item (2) of the theorem above, $L^2(S^1, \mu_g)$ is unitarily isomorphic to the cyclic sub-representation of $L^2(X, \mu)$ generated by $g$ under the unitary map $U_T$."

The statement in quotes appears on pg 184 of EW. I am not able to see what is the representation here. The group is probably $S^1$, and the vector space is $L^2(X, \mu)$. But the representation itself is not clear.

Also, how does item (2) of the theorem relate with representations?

Thank you.

Comment: Your version of the spectral theorem for normal operators is not true. Perhaps you were studying compact operators at the time?

Comment: Ah! Let me go back and revise. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know the classical Spectral Theorem for normal operators involving a projection-valued measure $P$, where $U = \int_{\sigma(U)}zdP(z)$?

Comment: I do not. Can you please articulate it in an answer and if possible give a reference. Thanks.

Comment: The spectral theorem involving spectral measures is not easily explained in a post. But it is the motivation for other versions, which is why other versions often seem unmotivated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a unitary representation $\pi:\mathbb{Z} \to Unit(H)$. This induces a *-homomorphism $\pi:L^1(\mathbb{Z}) \to Lin(H): (\pi(f)u,v):= \int f(n)(\pi(n)u,v)dn$ (Folland's harmonic analysis theorem $3.9$).

$L^1(\mathbb{Z})$ is a unital, commutative, Banach algebra whose spectrum can be identified with $S^1$, the dual of $\mathbb{Z}$ (Folland theorem 4.2).

Theorem $4.44$ of the same book then shows how to obtain part $(1)$ of the theorem in EW.

I'm guessing that for $(2)$, theorem $1.47$ of Folland's book is relevant.

Comment: Can you define what is meant by $Lin(H)$. Thanks.

Comment: These are bounded linear operators.